# Imputation from accounting identities

Tags: probability, missing-data

Suppose I have two sets of data:

- Remittances received from country X in country Y
- Remittances sent from country Y to country X

Such that they form an accounting identity.
I have socioeconomic data for donors and donees but no way to link the two.

Is there any reasonable way to either impute such relationship or to define a class of plausible relationships?